# How to cast and convert to datetime in where condition in t-sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to get last months worth of data from the table vis_p_activities_final and tried the query below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DPICD.vis_p_activities_final 
WHERE  DPICD.vis_p_activities_final.current_activity_code IN ( 
              'SDBPR', 'SDBPU', 'XSDBPU', 'SDBPUX' ) 
       AND CAST((DPICD.vis_p_activities_final.raised_date_time) AS DATETIME) >= 
           Dateadd(month, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`
```

the raised_date_time column is VARCHAR and I want to convert it to datetime for the filter. How can I do that?

Comment: Why is `DPICD.vis_p_activities_final.raised_date_time1` not a datetime already? Also, [3+ part naming for columns is to be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) in SQL Server; alias your objects and qualify your columns with that.

Comment: Because the output view requires raised_date_time to be varchar

Comment: That's a design flaw unto itself. And clearly that statement contradicts itself, because if it "needs" to be a `varchar`, then you shouldn't be trying to treat it like a `datetime` in your SQL. A `varchar` is *not* a `datetime`, by definition. The problem is your design; fix that and the problem goes away.

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 what output view? Are you sure there's any such requirement or should the client code simply change the display format? Storing dates as strings the worst thing you can do

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and sample data will help us help you. Perhaps an [_indexed computed column_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) would provide better performance. And "last months" _[sic]_ is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

you can use temp table as

```
declare @lastmonth datetime
   set @lastmonth = Dateadd(month, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

   SELECT *, CAST((DPICD.vis_p_activities_final.raised_date_time) AS DATETIME) as 
   'revised_date' into #tmp FROM DPICD.vis_p_activities_final 
   WHERE  DPICD.vis_p_activities_final.current_activity_code IN ( 
              'SDBPR', 'SDBPU', 'XSDBPU', 'SDBPUX' ) 
       `

   select * from #tmp where revised_date >= @lastmonth
```

Comment: Why do you need a temp table or a variable here? And this doesn't answer the question

Comment: to filter out required dates as his table structure does not allow direct filters to get last month data.

Comment: So either use a subquery or `CROSS APPLY` to store the converted value. There is **no need** for either the temp table or the variable, and they are both likely to cause significant performance issues

Comment: that makes sense however for simplicity of understanding data, temp table result helps.